# WordPress как переименовать/изменить wp-admin?

Tags: wordpress

У меня wordpress multisites. Можно ли изменить wp-admin url для всех сайтов (включая основной)?
Хочу что бы /wp-admin/ вообще не работал, но был доступен так /admin/.
Возможно ли это? Помогите - несколько часов уже гуглю, не могу найти решение.

Comment: А зачем вам это? Наверное, о безопасности думаете, да?

Comment: Можно, но не нужно. От этого только проблемы и никакой пользы.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/protect-wp-admin/